# Finding the coordinates of a line, having another line and an angle between them

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If I have a line, how do I find a second line that has the same extent as the first one, and crosses the first one in a given origin point and angle?

[For example, in this image I need to find x2 and y2, which are the only variables I don't have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm1su.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What are your thoughts on how to solve it? Where have you gotten stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give some hints.

1. Translate the points so that $(x_0, y_0)$ is at the origin. (Subtract $x_0$ from the $x$ coordinates and $y_0$ from the $y$ coordinates.)
2. Determine the angle that $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$ makes with the positive $x$ axis.
3. Subtract (or add, depending on the direction) $\theta$ from that angle, to get the angle that $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$ makes with the positive $x$ axis. Call this angle $\phi$.
4. Calculate the point that is a distance $d$ and angle $\phi$ from the origin. (Hint: use polar coordinates.)
5. Translate all of the points back to where they were by undoing step 1.

Can you take it from here?

Spoiler:

> Let $\alpha = \text{atan2} \frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$ where atan2 is the arctangent function that takes into account the signs of the arguments. Then $$x_2 = x_0 + d \cos(\alpha - \theta)$$ and $$y_2 = y_0 + d \sin(\alpha - \theta)$$

Comment: Not really :( . It's just for a software that uses vector graphics, I'm trying to create a geometric shape in the form of a protractor by doing a continuous touch gesture on a tablet. So I have all the coordinates of the line that is created by the touch gesture, and I need to create another line that is in a pre-determined angle from the first line, just like the image I provided, but I can't figure out the math.

Comment: Added a spoiler.